# Error en Ajax con consulta Mysqli

Tags: ajax, mysqli

Estoy intentando do recuperar unos datos desde [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) , sumarlos y mostrarlos mediante una consulta [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax)

**Javascript**

```
$(function () {
 $("#previousdate").on("click",function(){
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: base_url + 'index.php/welcome/showVentas',
    data:{
        'fecha' : $("#dateindex").val(),
    },
    success:function(e){
         alert(e);
    },
    error:function(e){
        alert("error");
    }
  });
 }
});
```

**php:**

```
function showVentas()
{
    $fecha = $_POST['fecha'];

    $fecha2 = explode("/", $fecha);
    $inicio = $fecha2[2] . "-" . $fecha2[1] . "-" . $fecha2[0] . " 00:00:00";
    $fin    = $fecha2[2] . "-" . $fecha2[1] . "-" . $fecha2[0] . " 23:59:59";

    $statement = "SELECT cash FROM pr_gadgets_information WHERE created <= '$fin' && created >= '$inicio'";

    $query     = $this->db->query($statement);

    $result = 0;

    while ($fila = $query->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $result += $fila['cash'];
    }
    echo $result;


}
```

Creo que el error está en mi función [php](/questions/tagged/php), ¿ Cuál es mi error? 
 - El error que obtengo actualmente es un error 500 en showVentas(), el cual desaparece cuando comento:

```
     while ($fila = $query->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $result += $fila['cash'];
    }
```

- `var_dump($query)` me devuelve:

> object(CI_DB_mysqli_result)#22 (8) {   ["conn_id"]=>   object(mysqli)#18 (19) {
>       ["affected_rows"]=>
>       int(5)
>       ["client_info"]=>
>       string(79) "mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: b5c5906d452ec590732a93b051f3827e02749b83 $"
>       ["client_version"]=>
>       int(50012)
>       ["connect_errno"]=>
>       int(0)
>       ["connect_error"]=>
>       NULL
>       ["errno"]=>
>       int(0)
>       ["error"]=>
>       string(0) ""
>       ["error_list"]=>
>       array(0) {
>       }
>       ["field_count"]=>
>       int(1)
>       ["host_info"]=>
>       string(25) "Localhost via UNIX socket"
>       ["info"]=>
>       NULL
>       ["insert_id"]=>
>       int(0)
>       ["server_info"]=>
>       string(30) "5.5.5-10.0.30-MariaDB-0+deb8u1"
>       ["server_version"]=>
>       int(50505)
>       ["stat"]=>
>       string(135) "Uptime: 2606  Threads: 1  Questions: 2426  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 46  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 109  Queries per
>   second avg: 0.930"
>       ["sqlstate"]=>
>       string(5) "00000"
>       ["protocol_version"]=>
>       int(10)
>       ["thread_id"]=>
>       int(420)
>       ["warning_count"]=>
>       int(0)   }   ["result_id"]=>   object(mysqli_result)#21 (5) {
>       ["current_field"]=>
>       int(0)
>       ["field_count"]=>
>       int(1)
>       ["lengths"]=>
>       NULL
>       ["num_rows"]=>
>       int(5)
>       ["type"]=>
>       int(0)   }   ["result_array"]=>   array(0) {   }   ["result_object"]=>   array(0) {   }   ["custom_result_object"]=>
>   array(0) {   }   ["current_row"]=>   int(0)   ["num_rows"]=>   NULL
>   ["row_data"]=>   NULL }

Comment: [Edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/63967/edit) y agrega la siguiente información: ¿Cual es el resultado o error que obtienes actualmente? ¿Cual es el resultado esperado? ¿Que devuelve `$this->db->query` o cual es el resultado de hacer `var_dump($query)`?

Comment: Cual es el error que recibes? te sugiero colocar el error. Como tienes tu codigo mira con alert(e.responseText) caso contrario mira los demas parámetros http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ a fin de obtenerlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema estaba en la parte del php, a causa de usar codeigniter no puedo usar:

```
while ($fila = $query->fetch_assoc())
{
    $result += $fila['cash'];
}
echo $result;
```

tengo que usar:

```
foreach ( $query->result_array() as $row)
{
   $result += $row['cash'];

}

echo $result;
```

Con ese cambio funciona perfectamente, gracias por vuestras respuestas

Answer (score 1):

Ejecutas la consulta pero no estas recuperando los resultados que trae.

También añadiría una validación a la fecha a parte, deberías escapar los datos o utilizar sentencias preparadas para evitar la inyección SQL.

```
function showVentas()
{
    $fecha = $_POST['fecha'];

    /* Validamos la fecha */
    // dd/mm/aaaa --> 11/01/2015
    $expresion_regular_fecha='/^([0][1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(\/|-)([0][1-9]|[1][0-2])\2(\d{4})$/'; 
    if (!preg_match($expresion_regular_fecha, $fecha))
    {
        return 'La fecha no es válida';
    }


    $fecha2 = explode("/", $fecha);
    $inicio = $fecha2[2] . "-" . $fecha2[1] . "-" . $fecha2[0] . " 00:00:00";
    $fin    = $fecha2[2] . "-" . $fecha2[1] . "-" . $fecha2[0] . " 23:59:59";

    $statement = "SELECT cash as total FROM pr_gadgets_information WHERE created <= '$fin' && created >= '$inicio'";

    $query     = $this->db->query($statement);

    $result = 0;

    /* despues de realizar la consulta necesitas traer los resultados */
    while ($fila = $query->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $result += $fila['cash'];
    }

    /*
    foreach ($query as $row)
    {
        $result = $result + $row['cash'];
    }
    */

    echo $result;


}
```

Igualmente pienso que si sólo quieres obtener la suma de los registros bien podrías hacerlo con la [funcion SUM()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_sum.asp) de SQL directamente.

Comment: Teoricamente la respuesta es correcta, pero me sigue dando un error 500, sin embargo al comentar el "While", no recibo ese error 500

Comment: Según la info de `var_dump` se está conectado con MySQLi: `object(CI_DB_mysqli_result)#22 (8) { ["conn_id"]=> object(mysqli)#18 (19)...`